# Unity-Soomla-iOS : SOOMLA SoomlaStore: Invalid product id error

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, soomla

I am stuck at this bug
Invalid product id (when trying to fetch item details): coin_pack_1
Expecting 3 products but only fetched 0 from iTunes Store

and when I try to buy I get
[*** ERROR ***] SOOMLA SoomlaStore: Invalid product id (when trying to fetch item details): coin_pack_1

I have tried EVERYTHING :(

deleting the app and trying again,
using sandbox test users,
creating new sandbox test users and use them,
double checked that the product id's match
double checked that the bundle id's match
setup inapps in itunes account MANY times
increased the version number in istoreassets script

I did all the above BUT I just keep getting this error, I have been following posts and tried everything mentioned but the error just wont go away. PLEASE HELP ME !!!

2017-10-27 17:13:53.147778 simpossible[725:195123] 2017-10-27 11:43:53 +0000 [Appodeal 2.1.0][error] Got error message from server: <(null)>
2017-10-27 11:43:53 +0000 [Appodeal 2.1.0][error] Got error message from server: <(null)>

2017-10-27 17:13:53.443893 simpossible[725:194886] [*** ERROR ***] SOOMLA SoomlaStore: Invalid product id (when trying to fetch item details): coin_pack_1

2017-10-27 17:13:53.444030 simpossible[725:194886] [*** ERROR ***] SOOMLA SoomlaStore: Invalid product id (when trying to fetch item details): coin_pack_2

2017-10-27 17:13:53.444110 simpossible[725:194886] [*** ERROR ***] SOOMLA SoomlaStore: Invalid product id (when trying to fetch item details): coin_pack_3

2017-10-27 17:13:53.444217 simpossible[725:194886] [*** ERROR ***] SOOMLA SoomlaStore: Expecting 3 products but only fetched 0 from iTunes Store

I checked the product id, they are same as in ituneconnects.
here is my code for that. .

public static VirtualGood VG_PRODUCT_1 = new SingleUseVG (
                                                     "20000 Coin",
                                                     "20000 Coin",
                                                     "coin_pack_1",
                                                     new PurchaseWithMarket ("coin_pack_1", 1.99));

In ituneconnects i have this id = coin_pack_1